# Composer dependency conflict

Tags: php, composer-php, guzzle

Running this `composer require intervention/image` throws this error:

```
Using version ^2.3 for intervention/image
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install intervention/image 2.3.1
- Conclusion: don't install intervention/image 2.3.2
- Installation request for intervention/image ^2.3 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2].
- intervention/image 2.3.0 requires guzzlehttp/psr7 ~1.1 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.1.0, 1.2.0].
- guzzlehttp/psr7 1.1.0 requires psr/http-message ~1.0 -> satisfiable by psr/http-message[1.0].
- guzzlehttp/psr7 1.2.0 requires psr/http-message ~1.0 -> satisfiable by psr/http-message[1.0].
- Conclusion: don't install psr/http-message 1.0


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

So it's caused by Guzzle (I'm using `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3"`). But I can't (or don't want) to update guzzle to 6.0 because it's not backward compatible, so I have to move a lot of code. Can I do something, like a trick, or do I have to update `guzzlehttp/guzzle` or `intervention/image`?

Comment: Does your dependency use Guzzle on top of your main app? If they are specifying two different version of Guzzle you can run into this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the alias method has a serious drawback: It won't work!

I doubt your usage of Guzzle 5 is the reason for your message, but for more investigation I'd need the content of your `composer.json`, and likely your `composer.lock` file as well.

The dependencies being added here are not too complicated. `intervention/image` depends on `guzzlehttp/psr7 ~1.1`, which depends on `psr/http-message ~1.0`. The Guzzle package is a brand new one which hasn't been used with previous versions of Guzzle 5.x, and the PSR package should also not conflict with anything - but this is exactly what Composer detects. However, decrypting the error messages of the SAT solver in Composer is not easy. The solver can easily create you a solution that works for all requirements, but pinpointing failure is very hard. Composer would do it for you if it was possible.

There is a tool that can help humans debug such a situation: https://packagist.org/packages/clue/graph-composer

It's a command line tool that is best installed with `composer global require clue/graph-composer`, and it also needs "graphviz" installed. Using it on your existing project will reveal all the package dependencies that are currently existing, and might give you a clue what might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you! This response really helps, it's clear and precise. Anyway I switched to a previous version of intervention/image, it's not important to have the latest version in my project. Many thanks!

Comment: @Sven Thanks for pointing out "clue/graph-composer". Its a nice tool for visualization of Composer dependencies. Do you know of tools doing the same, but without the heavy "graphviz" dependency?

Comment: I think there's no current product being able to draw graphs the way Graphviz does - at least not in the open source domain. A lot of knowledge about how to draw things went into that software, so it's probably not that easy to have a replacement. On the other hand, I had no serious problems installing it on several platforms (i.e. Linux and Windows) and make it available to the graph-composer package.

Comment: Wouldn't it be hilarious if there were dependency conflicts when installing graph-composer or graphviz?...

Answer (score 1):

You might use an alias to trick Composer into thinking that v5.3.0 of guzzle is actually v6.0.

Defining `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3 as 6.0"` will not work, because that's just an invalid string. You have to be specific about the version and insert 5.3.0, like so:

`composer.json`

```
{
    "require": {
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.3.0 as 6.0"
    }
}
```

You could also update your code to work with `guzzlehttp/guzzle` v6, but that's probably more work than changing few chars in composer.json. ,)

---

> It's a trick but it won't work. You can have a look at @Sven answer.

Its pretty obvious that you didn't test what i posted. Aliasing a version is one way to get it done. Its not the holy grail of fixing all dependency issues. Its a simple method to resolve a version clash.

```
[50.2MB/9.02s]   - Installing react/promise (v2.2.1)
[50.6MB/9.07s] Reading C:/Users/koch/AppData/Local/Composer/files/react/promise/3b6fca09c7d56321057fa8867c8dbe1abf648627.zip from cache
[50.6MB/9.08s]     Loading from cache
[50.6MB/9.08s]     Extracting archive
[50.7MB/9.47s]
[50.7MB/9.48s]     REASON: guzzlehttp/ringphp 1.1.0 requires react/promise ~2.0 -> satisfiable by react/promise[v2.0.0, v2.1.0, v2.2.0, v2.2.1].
[50.7MB/9.48s]
[50.7MB/9.49s]   - Installing guzzlehttp/streams (3.0.0)
[50.7MB/9.53s] Reading C:/Users/koch/AppData/Local/Composer/files/guzzlehttp/streams/47aaa48e27dae43d39fc1cea0ccf0d84ac1a2ba5.zip from cache
[50.7MB/9.54s]     Loading from cache
[50.7MB/9.54s]     Extracting archive
[50.7MB/9.92s]
[50.7MB/9.93s]     REASON: guzzlehttp/ringphp 1.1.0 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~3.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/streams[3.0.0].
[50.7MB/9.93s]
[50.7MB/9.94s]   - Installing guzzlehttp/ringphp (1.1.0)
[50.7MB/10.01s] Reading C:/Users/koch/AppData/Local/Composer/files/guzzlehttp/ringphp/dbbb91d7f6c191e5e405e900e3102ac7f261bc0b.zip from cache
[50.7MB/10.02s]     Loading from cache
[50.7MB/10.02s]     Extracting archive
[50.7MB/10.41s]
[50.7MB/10.41s]     REASON: guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.3.0 requires guzzlehttp/ringphp ^1.1 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/ringphp[1.1.0].
[50.7MB/10.41s]
[50.7MB/10.43s]   - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (5.3.0)
[50.7MB/10.49s] Reading C:/Users/koch/AppData/Local/Composer/files/guzzlehttp/guzzle/f3c8c22471cb55475105c14769644a49c3262b93.zip from cache
[50.7MB/10.51s]     Loading from cache
[50.7MB/10.51s]     Extracting archive
[50.7MB/11.66s]
[50.7MB/11.66s]     REASON: Required by root: Install command rule (install guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.3.0)
[50.7MB/11.66s]
[50.7MB/11.69s]   - Installing psr/http-message (1.0)
[50.7MB/11.77s] Reading C:/Users/koch/AppData/Local/Composer/files/psr/http-message/85d63699f0dbedb190bbd4b0d2b9dc707ea4c298.zip from cache
[50.7MB/11.78s]     Loading from cache
[50.7MB/11.78s]     Extracting archive
[50.7MB/11.91s]
[50.7MB/11.91s]     REASON: guzzlehttp/psr7 1.2.0 requires psr/http-message ~1.0 -> satisfiable by psr/http-message[1.0].
[50.7MB/11.91s]
[50.7MB/11.94s]   - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.2.0)
[50.7MB/11.98s] Reading C:/Users/koch/AppData/Local/Composer/files/guzzlehttp/psr7/4ef919b0cf3b1989523138b60163bbcb7ba1ff7e.zip from cache
[50.7MB/11.98s]     Loading from cache
[50.7MB/11.98s]     Extracting archive
[50.7MB/12.61s]
[50.7MB/12.61s]     REASON: intervention/image 2.3.2 requires guzzlehttp/psr7 ~1.1 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.1.0, 1.2.0].
[50.7MB/12.61s]
[50.7MB/12.64s]   - Installing intervention/image (2.3.2)
[50.7MB/12.73s] Reading C:/Users/koch/AppData/Local/Composer/files/intervention/image/1124ff3c6298f0dcf9edf9156623904d7a5c3428.zip from cache
[50.7MB/12.74s]     Loading from cache
[50.7MB/12.74s]     Extracting archive
[50.7MB/14.72s]
[50.7MB/14.72s]     REASON: Required by root: Install command rule (install intervention/image 2.3.0|install intervention/image 2.3.1|install intervention/image 2.3.2)
[50.7MB/14.72s]
[50.3MB/15.09s] intervention/image suggests installing ext-gd (to use GD library based image processing.)
[50.3MB/15.10s] intervention/image suggests installing ext-imagick (to use Imagick based image processing.)
[50.3MB/15.11s] intervention/image suggests installing intervention/imagecache (Caching extension for the Intervention Image library)
[50.4MB/15.17s] Writing lock file
```

Comment: It's a trick but it won't work. You can have a look at @Sven answer

Comment: It seems you didn't test it :) Let's base this composer.json on facts... i added the install log. Anyway..glad you solved the problem :)

Comment: You're right :), I did not tested. Now I've just tested, same problem, it does not work. Maybe on a fresh project, but using composer update I've got exactly the same error with same text (I've just copy/pasted your code and run composer update). Did you do something else? (or maybe there is something I don't understand)

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I used `composer clearcache` followed by `composer install -vvv --profile` with the composer snippet from above. It resolves and installs all packages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can try to use [aliases](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md).
It might be something like this:

`"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3 as 6.0"`

Comment: It's a trick but it won't work. You can have a look at @Sven answer